# Beautifulsoup4 installation error. bs4 folder not created

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Having issues installing beautifulsoup in python on win-8. I have already tried downloading the latest version from [here](http://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/). Installed it without errors through cmd setup.py install but bs4 folder is not created in c:\python\35-32\Lib\site-packages folder. What do I do? I am using python3.5.

There is a beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py3.5.egg file created

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem  too. How I solved this was:
1) Create a PATH in the cmd. On Windows 10 you can do this by right clicking the Window's icon in the bottom left hand corner, clicking Control Panel > System and Security > System. Then on the left hand side there should be 4 links, click the last one, Advanced system settings. Under the Advanced tab click Environment Variables, at the bottom of the window. Under System variables (the second box) find the variable called Path, select that, click edit, then in the new window click New on the right side. Type: C:\Python27;C:\Python27\python.exe (it might auto correct to C:\Python27). Then click 'okay'.

2) Open cmd and type python (press enter). The text field should start with >>> instead of C:\User(Name)>.If that happens it is working.

3) Access your beautifulsoup folder through cmd.

4) Once you are in your folder type:

```
    python setup.py install_lib
```

When I did this the first time I typed:

```
    python setup.py install
```

which gave me the same results you got.

That was a lot of text, so if you need any assistance ask and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: TY. After using `install_lib`, bs4 folder was finally created. But now the file beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py3.5.egg is missing. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: For me I program in Eclipse, so I just created a path to the beautifulsoup folder, because for some reason the .egg file wasn't working